# Return unique row and get rid of extraneous row in oracle sql query

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have an oracle query that is typically giving me three rows of results. Two are identical while the third is simply an extra row. How can I modify this query to obtain only the unique results. Here is the query statement:

```
select prt.oid, it.itemname, it1.itemname, prt1.oid from jrtp_rdb.jrtepartoccurrence prt
join jrtp_rdb.jnameditem it on it.oid = prt.oid
join jrtp_rdb.xdistribports x on x.oidorigin = prt.oid
join jrtp_rdb.xflowports x1 on x1.oiddestination = x.oiddestination
join jrtp_rdb.xgeneratesconnectionitems x2 on x2.oidorigin= x1.oidorigin
join jrtp_rdb.xownsimplieditems x3 on x3.oiddestination = x2.oiddestination
join jrtp_rdb.jnameditem it1 on it1.oid = x3.oidorigin
join jrtp_rdb.jrtepartoccurrence prt1 on prt1.oid = it1.oid
where prt.oid in
('00013885000000004C00426DEC534269');
```

The results are shown in the table below:

```
00013885000000004C00426DEC534269    Flange-120491   Gate Valve-65650    0001388500000000AB3BEAC87354D9BE
00013885000000004C00426DEC534269    Flange-120491   Gate Valve-65650    0001388500000000AB3BEAC87354D9BE
00013885000000004C00426DEC534269    Flange-120491   Flange-120491       00013885000000004C00426DEC534269
```

In this case I just want the first row since it gives the name of the flange connecting to the gate valve. How can I modify the query to just obtain the unique row and get rid of the extra third row?

Comment: How can that extra row be identified? `it.itemname = it1.itemname`? No duplicate exists?

Comment: Why the 3rd row is 'extra '- what is your logic. I suppose you could use `distinct` in your select to get rid of duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
select distinct prt.oid, it.itemname, it1.itemname, prt1.oid from jrtp_rdb.jrtepartoccurrence prt
join jrtp_rdb.jnameditem it on it.oid = prt.oid
join jrtp_rdb.xdistribports x on x.oidorigin = prt.oid
join jrtp_rdb.xflowports x1 on x1.oiddestination = x.oiddestination
join jrtp_rdb.xgeneratesconnectionitems x2 on x2.oidorigin= x1.oidorigin
join jrtp_rdb.xownsimplieditems x3 on x3.oiddestination = x2.oiddestination
join jrtp_rdb.jnameditem it1 on it1.oid = x3.oidorigin
join jrtp_rdb.jrtepartoccurrence prt1 on prt1.oid = it1.oid
where prt.oid in
('00013885000000004C00426DEC534269') and prt.oid<>prt1.oid
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to find duplicates is to add unique row identifiers, for example ROWIDs in case of real physical tables:

```sql
select prt.oid, it.itemname, it1.itemname, prt1.oid 
,count(distinct  prt.rowid)  prt_cnt
,count(distinct   it.rowid)   it_cnt
,count(distinct    x.rowid)    x_cnt
,count(distinct   x1.rowid)   x1_cnt
,count(distinct   x2.rowid)   x2_cnt
,count(distinct   x3.rowid)   x3_cnt
,count(distinct  it1.rowid)  it1_cnt
,count(distinct prt1.rowid) prt1_cnt
from jrtp_rdb.jrtepartoccurrence prt
join jrtp_rdb.jnameditem it 
     on it.oid = prt.oid
join jrtp_rdb.xdistribports x 
     on x.oidorigin = prt.oid
join jrtp_rdb.xflowports x1 
     on x1.oiddestination = x.oiddestination
join jrtp_rdb.xgeneratesconnectionitems x2 
     on x2.oidorigin= x1.oidorigin
join jrtp_rdb.xownsimplieditems x3 
     on x3.oiddestination = x2.oiddestination
join jrtp_rdb.jnameditem it1 
     on it1.oid = x3.oidorigin
join jrtp_rdb.jrtepartoccurrence prt1 
     on prt1.oid = it1.oid
where prt.oid in
('00013885000000004C00426DEC534269')
group by prt.oid, it.itemname, it1.itemname, prt1.oid;
```

Comment: ORA-01446: cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc.
01446. 00000 -  "cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc."
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: I get error message shown above when I run the query

Comment: @PatStarks as I said in the first sentence, you can use ROWIDs only on real physical tables. In case of views, you need to use their unique row identifiers. Do you have columns like ID in them?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
With cte as(
select prt.oid, it.itemname, it1.itemname, prt1.oid,
RANK() OVER(
            PARTITION BY it.itemname,prt.oid
            ORDER BY it.itemname,prt.oid DESC) r
 from jrtp_rdb.jrtepartoccurrence prt
join jrtp_rdb.jnameditem it on it.oid = prt.oid
join jrtp_rdb.xdistribports x on x.oidorigin = prt.oid
join jrtp_rdb.xflowports x1 on x1.oiddestination = x.oiddestination
join jrtp_rdb.xgeneratesconnectionitems x2 on x2.oidorigin= x1.oidorigin
join jrtp_rdb.xownsimplieditems x3 on x3.oiddestination = x2.oiddestination
join jrtp_rdb.jnameditem it1 on it1.oid = x3.oidorigin
join jrtp_rdb.jrtepartoccurrence prt1 on prt1.oid = it1.oid
where prt.oid in
('00013885000000004C00426DEC534269')
)

select * from cte where r=1
```